# Showing the lemma $\frac 1 {e(n+1)} \leq R^n-R^{n+1}$ for some $0<R<1$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, inequality

My original goal was to show that, if $f$ is analytic on the unit disk and $|f(z)|\leq \frac 1 {1-|z|}$, then $|f^{(n)}(0)|\leq e(n+1)!$

I have managed to show that, given $0<R<1$, we can use Cauchy's estimate to obtain $|f^{(n)}(0)| \leq n!R^{-n}\frac 1 {1-|R|}= \frac {n!} {R^n-R^{n+1}}$. Now, this is $\leq e(n+1)!$ when $\frac 1 {e(n+1)} \leq R^n-R^{n+1}$.

So, if I can show that $\frac 1 {e(n+1)} \leq R^n-R^{n+1}$ for at least one $0<R<1$, I'll be done.

This is obviously true when $n=0$, but I don't know how to show the general case.

Comment: What if you pick $R = 1-\frac{1}{n}$?

Comment: @Conrad Substituting $R=1-1/n$, I see that $(n+1)(R^n-R^{n+1})=(1-\frac 1 n)^n(1+\frac 1 n)$. If I can show that this is $\geq e^{-1}$, I'm done. I suspect the fact $lim[(1-\frac 1 n)^n]=e^{-1}$ will help, although I don't see how to fill in the missing steps yet.

Comment: Actually it is better to take $1-\frac{1}{n+1}$ as then you get a term in $n$ that is clearly decreasing to $\frac{1}{e}$ - you can check the derivative if you smooth it with $0<x<1$

Comment: @Conrad I finished the problem, thanks.

Comment: Great - always when needing to bound $R^n$ for $R$ close to 1, $1 - \frac{1}{n}$ (or something similar with $n+1$ or $n-1$ etc) is the one to try